# PHP, AJAX, checkbox filtering for MySQL, and switching between AND/OR

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, checkbox, filtering

I am trying to use checkboxes to filter search results. In the `SELECT` query, `AND` and `OR` will both need to be used depending on how many and which checkboxes were checked. Here is the HTML:

```
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Filter Results</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>By chipset manufacturer:</td>
                <td><input name="by_amd" id="amdF" type="checkbox" value="1" />AMD</td>
                <td><input name="by_ati" id="atiF" type="checkbox" value="2" />ATI</td>
                <td><input name="by_nvid" id="nvidiaF" type="checkbox" value="3" />nVidia</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>By year released:</td>
                <td><input name="by_2014" id="2014F" type="checkbox" value="2014" />2014</td>
                <td><input name="by_2013" id="2013F" type="checkbox" value="2013" />2013</td>
                <td><input name="by_2012" id="2012F" type="checkbox" value="2012" />2012</td>
                <td><input name="by_2011" id="2011F" type="checkbox" value="2011" />2011</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

And the PHP:

```
// create base SELECT query
        $select = 'SELECT GPUProductName, GPUChip, GPUReleaseDate, GPUBus, GPUMemory, GPUClock, GPUMemClock, GPUAddStats'; 
        $from = ' FROM GPU'; 
        $where = ' WHERE TRUE'; 
        // create search filters
        $opts = isset($_POST['filterOpts']) ? $_POST['filterOpts'] : array('');
        // By chipset manufacturer
        if (in_array("by_amd", $opts)){
          $where .= " AND CMid = 1";
        }

        if (in_array("by_ati", $opts)){
          $where .= " AND CMid = 2";
        }

        if (in_array("by_nvid", $opts)){
          $where .= " AND CMid = 3";
        }
        // by release year
        if (in_array("by_2014", $opts)){
          $where .= " AND YEAR(GPUReleaseDate)='2014'";
        }
        // build complete SELECT query
        $query = $select . $from . $where;
        return $query;
```

If you choose 'by ATI' and 'by AMD' the SELECT statement should be `WHERE CMid = 2 OR CMid = 1`, respectively. If you then add 'by 2014' the SELECT statement should be `WHERE YEAR(GPUReleaseYear) = 2014 AND CMid = 2 OR CMid = 1`. Basically, filters picked from the same category (so to speak) should be joined by OR and filters picked from different categories should be joined with AND. How do I, in PHP, create the correct SELECT statement based on how many checkboxes were checked from the same and/or different categories?

Comment: Just all AND in cmid to OR it should work  as expected .
WHERE TRUE OR cond1 OR cond2 OR cond3 AND year .. that all needed right.

Comment: It doesn't, because the statement reads `WHERE TRUE OR CMid = 1 OR CMid = 2`. Meaning it just pulls everything from the table regardless of the filter used.

Comment: OR statements should be within parentheses like; WHERE (CMid=1 OR CMid=2) AND (YEAR(GPUReleaseYear)=2014 OR YEAR(GPUReleaseYear)=2012)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$query = 'SELECT GPUProductName, GPUChip, GPUReleaseDate, GPUBus, GPUMemory, GPUClock, GPUMemClock, GPUAddStats FROM GPU WHERE '; 

$manufacturers=array();
if(isset($_POST['by_amd']) $manufacturers[]="CMid=1";
if(isset($_POST['by_ati']) $manufacturers[]="CMid=2";
if(isset($_POST['by_nvid']) $manufacturers[]="CMid=3";
$query.='('.implode(' OR ',$manufacturers).')';

$query.=' AND ';

$years=array();
if(isset($_POST['by_2014']) $years[]="YEAR(GPUReleaseDate)=2014";
if(isset($_POST['by_2013']) $years[]="YEAR(GPUReleaseDate)=2013";
if(isset($_POST['by_2012']) $years[]="YEAR(GPUReleaseDate)=2012";
if(isset($_POST['by_2011']) $years[]="YEAR(GPUReleaseDate)=2011";
$query.='('.implode(' OR ',$years).')';

return $query;
```

Comment: Of course, you have to ensure (e.g. using JavaScript) that at least one checkbox was checked within a group manufactirers/years.

Comment: Yeah, my jQuery and AJAX work just fine, it was the PHP I was having issues with. Thank you!

Comment: Also, should I be sanitizing these inputs? I know they're for checkboxes, and no data is being inserted into the DB, but just for safety's sake?

Comment: No, there's no sanitizing checkboxes! If checkbox is set, the value "On" is sent, if checkbox is not set - nothing is sent (that is problem many times). So checking with isset($_POST['checkboxname']) is enough.

Comment: I thought as much. For extra precaution I made a new DB user that only has SELECT privileges anyway. I just need to minimize XSS attacks and SQL injection. Thank you!